# Load jquery action on link menu click/node load

Tags: nodes, javascript, rules

So what I would like to do is great a sliding door effect for my drupal site using jquery-ui action. Does anyone know of examples or a module for this?

Also I would like the action to execute on two triggers. 
            -open close sliding door on "menu link to new node click"
            -close sliding door once node is loaded

I've seen example for what I want to do and I know that you can insert jquery-ui. All I need to know is where do I need to insert the jqurey-ui. Examples would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what page you need to add the script, adding jquery_ui is fairly straightforward if you know which component it is.

You should add the following line in the template.php (changing the ui.autocomplete to what you need)

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.autocomplete');
```

The following page is extremely useful https://drupal.org/node/171213

Update as described in comments

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
    if(arg(0)=='node' && arg(1) === 3)) {
        $node = node_load(arg(1));
        drupal_add_js('system', 'ui.autocpmplete);}
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think you nailed it on the head. " depends on what page you need to add the script" So this means that the line you mention, controls the action of the way the whole system? Lets say I want to change node/3, I would change the line or add a line? So drupal_add_library('node/3', 'ui.youractiontojqueryscript'); , would be what you mean?

Comment: not quite, the second argument 'system' is the module that registered the js. If you want only to load it on the node/3 
hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) then inside that function use some logic to add to the nodes that match the node id you want ..see above

Comment: Thanks. Ya here's basically what I will be trying to accomplish, but not by pulling a rope and will only close when link to certain node is clicked. http://rawgallery.us/curtains/index.html  . I'll see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.buildinternet.com/live/curtains/curtains.zip